# Spring Boot - Thymeleaf - redirect to Error page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot app. with Thymeleaf

I have this in my property file:

```
# max file size - default 1MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
# max request size - default 10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=25MB
```

this controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private final static String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(PATH)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "error/genericError";
    }


}
```

and this Error page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<body>
 <div class="container">

        <div class="jumbotron text-center">

            <h1>Uh-oh! Something Happened!</h1>
            <!--  As we are using Thymeleaf, you might consider using
                  ${#httpServletRequest.requestURL}. But that returns the path
                  to this error page.  Hence we explicitly add the url to the
                  Model in some of the example code. -->
            <p th:if="${url}">
                <b>Page:</b> <span th:text="${url}">Page URL</span>
            </p>

            <p th:if="${timestamp}" id='created'>
                <b>Occurred:</b> <span th:text="${timestamp}">Timestamp</span>
            </p>

            <p>Devopsbuddy has encountered an error. Please contact support
                by clicking <a th:href="@{/contact}">here.</a></p>

            <p>Support may ask you to right click to view page source.</p>

            <!--
              // Hidden Exception Details  - this is not a recommendation, but here is
              // how you hide an exception in the page using Thymeleaf
              -->
            <div th:utext="'&lt;!--'" th:remove="tag"></div>
            <div th:utext="'Failed URL: ' +  ${url}" th:remove="tag">${url}</div>
            <div th:utext="'Exception: ' + ${exception.message}" th:remove="tag">${exception.message}</div>
            <ul th:remove="tag">
                <li th:each="ste : ${exception.stackTrace}" th:remove="tag"><span
                        th:utext="${ste}" th:remove="tag">${ste}</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div th:utext="'--&gt;'" th:remove="tag"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

but when I try to upload a file > 10MB

I don't see the error Page, but this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation from your controller method, this annotation indicates that the object returned should be automatically serialized into JSON and passed back into the response offered to the client.

Your code should look like:

```java
@RequestMapping(PATH)
public String getErrorPath() {
  return "error/genericError";
}
```

Where, as indicated by @JustAnotherDeveloper, `error/genericError` matches a valid file (HTML, jsp, etcetera) located in the appropriate folder, in your case, your custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

Your return variable is a String, you want to return a view, like this (assuming Error is template name):

```
    @RequestMapping(PATH)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView getErrorPath() {
            return new ModelAndView("Error");
    }
```

Comment: Returning a string is fine, provided that the returned string matches the name of a HTML file located in the appropriate folder (src/resources/templates, if my memory is any good).

Answer (score 0):

Returned Error page must be mapped properly :

One way to do it through Spring Boot application.properties file :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp (or) html
```

Sample Controller :

```
@GetMapping(value = "login")
public String getLoginPage() {
    return "dummyPage";
}
```